# Sticky footer with adjustable height

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm trying to have a sticky footer on my page but with a twist compared to what I've seen before.

The top of the footer as to always be sticky at 50px after the content and a green color as to fill the rest of the footer until the end of the page.

You can see an example on http://enviro2012.tapagecommunication.com

The problem is even better illustrate if you clicl on the "send" button in the Facebook plugin at the bottom of the page.

Let me know if you need more info! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this one before. I tried all sorts of methods, including checking the window height against the vertical position of the footer, then setting the footer height to the difference. It didn't work too badly across most browsers.

However, the most simple (and fast-rendering) solution was to add enough bottom padding to the footer to cover the gap on most window sizes. Assuming your content is always going to fill the majority of the page, a few hundred pixels should be more than enough – and renders properly the first time the page loads.